# Using .Distinct() on certain rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq query which returns all of the data stored in a table based on a where clause as a list:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue.Where(x=>x.ManID == id).ToList();
```

This returns 23 items, but some of those items have some columns which contains duplicate data, I'll call them ColumnA, ColumnB and ColumnD. I've tried:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue.Where(x=>x.ManID == id)
                .Distinct().ToList();
```

But this just returns the same 23 rows. What I'd like is if I could specify the columns I want to have distinct values, something like:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue.Where(x=>x.ManID == id)
                .Distinct(x=> new { x.ColumnA, x.ColumnB, x.ColumnD }).ToList();
```

Is this possible or should I look for a new way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try combining `GroupBy` and `First`:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue
    .Where(x => x.ManID == id)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ColumnA, x.ColumnB, x.ColumnD })
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Just an adjustment to this: I had to use FirstOrDefault() as First() threw an error, but this worked perfectly thanks! I'll accept as answer when I'm able too!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. If this is within something like LINQ to SQL, I'd use `GroupBy`:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue
                              .Where(x=>x.ManID == id)
                              .GroupBy(x=> new { x.ColumnA, 
                                                 x.ColumnB, 
                                                 x.ColumnD })
                              .Select(g => g.First())
                              .ToList();
```

(EDIT: Note that using `First` really *should* be fine here - you shouldn't need to use `FirstOrDefault()`, as each group must have at least one entry in order to even exist.)

In LINQ to Objects, I'd use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) and its `DistinctBy` method:

```
List<Catalogue> data = context.Catalogue
                              .Where(x=>x.ManID == id)
                              .DistinctBy(x=> new { x.ColumnA, 
                                                    x.ColumnB, 
                                                    x.ColumnD })
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `IEqualityComparer` for the 3 properties that can be used with `Distinct()`.

[IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)